# Validation rule - access other field CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I try to write a custom validation rule and need all other fields of the model data that gonna be save to make that validation happen. I can't find a way to pass all data to the custom validation rule.

Array to validate:

```
[User]
    [Name] => 'Bob'
    [Message] => 'this is my message'
```

Validate:

```
public $validate = array(
'Message' => array(
   'rule' => 'customValidateFunction'
   )
);
```

Custom Validate Function:

```
public function customValidateFunction($messageArray){
   $valueOfMessage = $messageArray['Message'];
   $valueOfName = ?    
   return TRUE;
 }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do this sort of complex validation in the controller where all of the data is available?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins In general, validation *does* belong in the model, validating multiple fields in a validation rule seems like a 'valid' approach?

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using? What *other* fields do you need (I only see 'Name' and 'Message' in your example) and what is the result of debugging `$this->data` in your custom validate function? (it *should* contain all the data that is set to be saved)

Comment: $this->data works. Thanks